# A connection error in remote mode of Titan-1.0.0+Hbase-0.98.20 using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, titan

I am learning Titan database. I have run it successfully in local-mode. Now, I am trying to use Titan database in "Remote Server Mode" introduced in Titan-documentation. My Titan version is Titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.

I have clusters in my LAN including `cloud12` and `cloud13`. I installed hadoop-1.2.1 on it, the master is `cloud12` and the slave is `cloud13`.

I want to test the performance about create a graph, so I design to start my Hbase-0.98.20 in pseudo-distributed-mode on machine `cloud12` with independent zookeeper-3.4.6 and elasticsearch on `cloud12`.(I modified `hbase-env.sh`, and use default port `2181` in `zoo.cfg`)

Hadoop and HBase are seems like working regularly, I checked two servers by Jps and I also checked HBase through HBase shell.

Here are my configuration of `hbase-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://cloud12:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.master.port</name>
<value>60000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/Titan/hbase/zookeeperDir</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/Titan/hbase/tmpDir</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
<value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
<value>600</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Although when I ran my program in Eclipse on the other machine in LAN which named `cloud6`（I installed Titan-1.0.0 on this machine）, a confused error information printed in my output logs.

Here is the error constantly repeated in my output

> 789  [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.12.148:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x12d3a4e9, quorum=192.168.12.148:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
>
> 870  [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper  - Process identifier=hconnection-0x12d3a4e9 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=192.168.12.148:2181
>
> 878  [main-SendThread(192.168.12.148:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server 192.168.12.148/192.168.12.148:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
>
> 1030 [main-SendThread(192.168.12.148:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to 192.168.12.148/192.168.12.148:2181, initiating session
>
> 1049 [main-SendThread(192.168.12.148:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session establishment complete on server 192.168.12.148/192.168.12.148:2181, sessionid = 0x15654717951001b, negotiated timeout = 40000
>
> 1054 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry  - ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null

ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null？ I really confused about it. I tried to solve problem and I found my error are similar to many others, but I can't get clear answer from Google or other websites. Is there an error in my design of architecture? or configuration error?

I can ensure that my hosts and the time of cluster are all correct. Here is a part of my program to connect Hbase on `cloud12` from `cloud6`, is anything wrong or lackness in my code ?

```
  public static final String INDEXNAME = "search"; 
  ...
  BaseConfiguration conf=new BaseConfiguration();
  conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "hbase");
  conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", "192.168.12.148");//ip of cloud12
  conf.setProperty("storage.tablename", "graph1");
  conf.setProperty("index." + INDEXNAME + ".backend", "elasticsearch");
  conf.setProperty("index." + INDEXNAME + ".hostname", "192.168.12.148"); 
  conf.setProperty("index." + INDEXNAME + ".elasticsearch.local-mode", false);  
  conf.setProperty("index." + INDEXNAME + ".elasticsearch.client-only", true);
```

Comment: Note that the "ClusterId read in ZooKeeper is null" is an `INFO` level message. I don't think you mentioned it, but are you able to connect to `graph1` with your code despite the `INFO` message?

Comment: @JasonPlurad Thanks for your response.I can't connect to graph1 with my code. On the one hand, I checked Hbase shell. On the other hand, I set some flags in my code by using java class ”Calendar“ to compute the time. It can be printed to .txt in local-mode. But in remote mode, above error informations repeated in output and finally seems like suspend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to check since you are using an [external Zookeeper](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book.html#d1984e11609) ensemble:

1. Add the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` property value in `hbase-site.xml`. The value should be a comma-separated list of your Zookeeper nodes. It defaults to `localhost`.
2. Add `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false` to the `hbase-env.sh`. It defaults to `true`.
3. Make sure that the `zookeeper.znode.parent` property value in `hbase-site.xml` matches the value in your Titan configuration with `storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent`. It defaults to `/hbase`. If these values don't match, the [Titan connection to HBase will hang](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/PJW64yyziqE/OxIHljVfBQAJ).
4. Make sure that the `clientPort` property value in `zoo.cfg` matches the `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` value in `hbase-site.xml` and also matches the `storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` value in your Titan configuration. It defaults to `2181`. If these don't match, you would see connection exceptions in the logs.
5. Make sure that the Zookeeper nodes are listening on the `clientPort` using an accessible IP address (not `localhost`).

Once you've verified that you can connect to your Titan table, I think that the `INFO` messages are safe to ignore. You can toggle the logging level through settings in [`log4j.properties`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/WkAXMbg5vYU/tt53_mRHBQAJ):

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper=WARN
```

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1240) against Titan to investigate why the Zookeeper client connections are happening so frequently.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, adding property in hbase-site.xml and modified log4j (I modified hbase-env.sh before I posted problem). I can filter these INFO messages now. But I still not able to connect my remote Hbase. Program process seems suspend. I waited it for a long time, although I can't observe my flags printed and I can not find any table created in hbase shell. Why result in the process suspend ? Is my way to verify the connection have something wrong? If it's incorrect, could I get approaches to test whether I connect Titan table successfully?

Comment: added a couple more suggestions to try

Comment: This answer is correct and helped me solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem too.
just upgrade zookeeper3.4.5 to zookeeper3.4.6,and synchronize the time,
but there are  many INFO message still, so i  modified log4j like that:

log4j.properties:
`log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper=WARN`

just ok,