# Titan JAVA API connection error?

Tags: titan

I want to load data into titan ,which's backend is hbase.So I changed the example from https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java 
 a little.But it ocurred many Exceptions when i connect.

> Exception in thread "main" com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not open global configuration
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStandaloneGlobalConfiguration(Backend.java:451)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1322)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:84)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:139)
>       at titantest.TitanLoad.main(TitanLoad.java:106)
>   Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:759)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureColumnFamilyExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:831)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.openDatabase(HBaseStoreManager.java:456)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.KeyColumnValueStoreManager.openDatabase(KeyColumnValueStoreManager.java:29)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStandaloneGlobalConfiguration(Backend.java:449)
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.translateException(RpcRetryingCaller.java:229)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:202)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:299)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:278)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:140)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.(ClientScanner.java:135)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:845)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:600)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:364)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:281)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseAdmin1_0.tableExists(HBaseAdmin1_0.java:70)
>       at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:753)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:434)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:60)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1139)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1106)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:293)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:147)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:56)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>       ... 19 more

Here is the code:

```
TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.build().set("storage.backend","hbase").set("storage.hostname","192.168.200.121,192.168.200.115")
            .set("storage.hbase.table","mytitan").set("storage.hbase.ext.zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure").set("storage.port",2181).open();
```

BTW,I can connect to the Hbase cluster,it looks fine.

Comment: What version of HBase are you trying to use? Check out the Titan [version compatibility matrix](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html).

Comment: hbase-1.0.0-cdh5.4.0

Comment: @JasonPlurad hbase-1.0.0-cdh5.4.0

Comment: did you try the suggestions in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763428/a-connection-error-in-remote-mode-of-titan-1-0-0hbase-0-98-20-using-java/38770471#38770471